# need to select query or delete query to get this result or delete duplicate data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, sql-delete

i get data and i want to select or delete query to get this result expected

sql server query

```
select *,
         row_number() over (order by (select '' )) as seqnum
  from [elo].[dbo].[objkeys] 
  where parentid in (select parentid
                     from [elo].[dbo].[objekte] inner join
                          [elo].[dbo].[objkeys] 
                           on objid = parentid 
                     where objmask = '52' and okeydata like 'approve'
                  )
```

////
try this query but not ok

with cte AS(
select *,
             row_number() over (order by (select '' )) as seqnum
      from [elo].[dbo].[objkeys] 
      where parentid in (select parentid
                         from [elo].[dbo].[objekte] inner join
                              [elo].[dbo].[objkeys] 
                               on objid = parentid 
                         where objmask = '52' and okeydata like 'approve'
                      )
) Delete cte where seqnum >1

actual result

```
parentid    okeyno      okeyname        okeydata            
 652          0          NAME             uwk           
 652          1         NUMBER             1        
 652          2         ALAIETIMAD      approve     
 652          51        ELO_FNAME       16.jpg      

 653          0         NAME              uwk           
 653          1        NUMBER              1        
 653          2       ALAIETIMAD         approve        
 653         51       ELO_FNAME          16.jpg     

 656          0         NAME              b     
 656          1        NUMBER             1     
 656          2       ALAIETIMAD        approve     
 656         51       ELO_FNAME          14.jpg     

 657         0      NAME                  b     
 657         1      NUMBER                1     
 657         2      ALAIETIMAD         approve      
 657         51     ELO_FNAME          16.jpg       

 661         0      NAME              abdalah       
 661         1      NUMBER              1       
 661         2      ALAIETIMAD        approve       
 661         51     ELO_FNAME         16.jpg        

 662         0      NAME             abdalah        
 662         1      NUMBER             1        
 662         2      ALAIETIMAD       approve        
 662         51     ELO_FNAME        16.jpg
```

need result to be

```
parentid    okeyno      okeyname        okeydata            
 652          0      NAME                 uwk           
 652          1     NUMBER                 1        
 652          2     ALAIETIMAD         approve      
 652          51    ELO_FNAME          16.jpg       


 656          0     NAME                 b      
 656          1     NUMBER               1      
 656          2     ALAIETIMAD       approve        
 656         51     ELO_FNAME        14.jpg     



 661         0      NAME             abdalah        
 661         1      NUMBER             1        
 661         2      ALAIETIMAD       approve        
 661         51     ELO_FNAME        16.jpg
```

Comment: Please explain the logic.

Comment: get approve data for user once

Comment: delete duplicate data for same name prop in okeyname

Comment: `objmask like 52` either doesn't do what you want it to do or is written in a needlessly confusing way. `LIKE` operates only on string types, so the integer literal `52` will need an implicit conversion. It's functionally identical to `objmask = '52'` (but you probably want `objmask = 52`). Avoid needless conversions; they can have bad effects on performance if an index gets skipped that way.

Comment: ok Jeroen Mostert

Comment: need to get result no duplicate in approve for same user like uwk or abdalah Jeroen Mostert

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
select *,
         row_number() over (order by (select '' )) as seqnum
  from [elo].[dbo].[objkeys] 
  where parentid in (select parentid
                     from [elo].[dbo].[objekte] inner join
                          [elo].[dbo].[objkeys] 
                           on objid = parentid 
                     where objmask = '52' and okeydata like 'approve'
                  )
) as t
where parentid in
(
SELECT DISTINCT min(parentid) FROM 
(
select *,
         row_number() over (order by (select '' )) as seqnum
  from [elo].[dbo].[objkeys] 
  where parentid in (select parentid
                     from [elo].[dbo].[objekte] inner join
                          [elo].[dbo].[objkeys] 
                           on objid = parentid 
                     where objmask = '52' and okeydata like 'approve'
                  )
) as t2
where okeyname = 'NAME'
group by okeyno,okeyname,okeydata
)
```

Comment: give me error in where parentid in
(
SELECT DISTINCT min(parentid) FROM 
(

Comment: @AbdullahShasban it was missing the tables alias.